# Creating a type alias by deriving from a generic class in C#

Tags: c#, generics, alias, derived-class, type-alias

I have a class with some generic parameters that's a pain to type out in the dozen classes it's used in.

```
public abstract class StateBase<StatesList, StateData>
    where StatesList : class
    where StateData : class
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    protected StatesList stateList;
    protected StateData stateData;

    public StateBase(StatesList stateList, StateData stateData)
    {
        Name = this.GetType().Name;
        this.stateList = stateList;
        this.stateData = stateData;
    }

    public abstract bool CanTransitionTo(StateBase<StatesList, StateData> newState);
    public abstract void Enter();
    public abstract StateBase<StatesList, StateData> Tick();
    public abstract void Exit();
}
```

I'm familiar with the typedef feature of C/C++ and rather miss it right now. I know C#'s closest feature is the "using" directive, allowing you to make an alias scoped to a single file. I may just go back to that failing this, but for now, these classes keep changing and I'd like something a little more fire and forget.

So, I tried to solve the alias problem a little more elegantly by making a new class that derives from the above class with all the generic parameters filled in.

```
public abstract class AIState : StateMachine.StateBase<UnitAIStateList, AIStateData>
{
    public abstract override bool CanTransitionTo(AIState newState);
    public abstract override void Enter();
    public abstract override void Exit();
    public abstract override new AIState Tick();
}
```

As you can guess, C# didn't let me get away with it that easily. The base class' `Tick()` returns the generic version. My derived class substitutes in the actual types. It looks like it should work, as AIState is a type of the same thing it's asking for:

```
'AIState.Tick()': return type must be 'StateBase<UnitAIStateList, AIStateData>' to match overridden member 'StateBase<UnitAIStateList, AIStateData>.Tick()'
```

I suspect the fact that the reason this is failing is because C# doesn't implement type covariance, a feature I'm not terribly familiar with. But, as it were, I'm not familiar enough with it to really know if it's my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things;

1) I would consider your choice to require a `StateBase<StatesList, StateData>` type result from your `Tick` method.  What's the absolute minimum type you would need to use? 
 Would `object` be enough?

2) If you really require a "same as type" return value, then you'll have to use generics in a circular manner, like so:

```
public abstract class StateBase<StatesList, StateData, TChildType>
 where StatesList : class
 where StateData : class
 where TChildType : StateBase<StatesList, StateData, TChildType> //notice addition of TChildType
{
    public string Name { get; protected set; }
    protected StatesList stateList;
    protected StateData stateData;

    public StateBase(StatesList stateList, StateData stateData)
    {
        Name = this.GetType().Name;
        this.stateList = stateList;
        this.stateData = stateData;
    }

    public abstract bool CanTransitionTo(TChildType newState);
    public abstract void Enter();
    public abstract TChildType Tick();
    public abstract void Exit();
}

public class DerivedState : StateBase<string, string, DerivedState>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: The Tick() function can return a new state to transition to. I've considered changing this, considering that it now has a hard limitation that's been lifted elsewhere, but I would consider that sort of irrelevant to the question since the same problem exists with CanTransitionTo.

This is part of a state machine used to control AI in a first-person shooter. `StateBase` is the common framework for all states.

Comment: @RossLombardi Seeing as you're using the StateMachine pattern, could I go on a slight tangent and suggest using the `Stateless` state machine nuget package.  It'll provide you with a simple way to configure state machines and handle transitions etc.  Just a thought.  There are other StateMachine frameworks of course ^^